# No scanners detected after upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: 20.04

Simple scan says no scanners detected after upgrade from Ubuntu 18 LTS. Printer and scanner worked with previous V18 LTS. Tried reinstalling hplip-3.20.11, but no help. Printer device is HP M127fw connected to USB.

Comment: Have you tried to install `hp-plugin` ?

Comment: Yes, but it does not seem to work: It ends with:File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 512, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '('lsb_release', '-a')' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Comment: sh hplip-3.20.3-plugin.run dies with:
Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes python-pyqt5'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
error: Package install command failed with error code 100

Comment: after sudo apt install hplip
and then  hp-setup
simple scan now finds the scanner and lists it, but then fails with "Failed to scan. Unable to connect to scanner"

Comment: Run `hp-plugin` .

Comment: hp-plugin ends with:    File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 512, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '('lsb_release', '-a')' returned non-zero exit status 1.  The dialogue just waits for me to click next again and same output in terminal happens.

Comment: You have to check two things: output of `lsb_release -a`, your Python environment (do you use Anaconda?).

Comment: Thank you, NOrbert.                                                                                                  No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release: 20.04
Codename: focal
I do not know what Anaconda is.